# Add class to div on scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see I have a number of dots lined vertically! On scrolling down it works, as one scrolls the next dot gets a class thats chnages the style of the ball, I want the exact same to happen when i scroll up but it is not working! Please any input is appreciated!

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/rREpJP) for your reference!

below the html, css and javascript:

```js
var activeMilestone = function() {
  var milestoneBalls = $('.dot');
  milestoneBalls[0].classList.add("active");
  window.onscroll = function() {
    milestoneBalls.each(function(i, v) {
      var thisBall = $(this);
      var nextBall = milestoneBalls[i + 1];
      var prevBall = milestoneBalls[i - 1];
      var thisPositionTop = thisBall.offset().top + ($(this).parent().height() / 3);
      var winScroll = window.scrollY;
      if (thisPositionTop <= winScroll) {
        nextBall.classList.add("active");
        thisBall.addClass("inactive");
      }
      if (thisPositionTop >= winScroll) {
        //this.classList.add("inactive_ball");
      }
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(activeMilestone);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.info_wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.dot {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border: solid 4px green;
}

.active {
  border: solid 4px yellow;
  background-color: red;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: maroon;
  border: solid 4px green;
}

.text {}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The short answer is because you don't handle it. (it should be the prevBall). However, normally this is solved like a zoning, where the current dot reach that zone, it will be active every other inactive. Oh, and also because you using active and inactive, when you scrolling up, it will be both. For inactive you don't need special class, format all as inactive, and just put active on which should be active in that time and overwrite with that class the necessary styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this logic performs the same that you were doing already.  With the added logic of, if the element should not advance, and we are not the first element, we check to see if the previous ball should be active.  And if so, we make it active.

```js
var activeMilestone = function() {
  var milestoneBalls = $('.dot');
  
  milestoneBalls.eq(0).addClass('active');
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var activeBall = milestoneBalls.filter('.active');
    var activeBallIndex = milestoneBalls.index( activeBall );
    var activeBallPositionTop = activeBall.offset().top + (activeBall.parent().height() / 3);
    
    if (activeBallPositionTop <= window.scrollY) {
      activeBall.removeClass('active');
      milestoneBalls.eq( activeBallIndex + 1).addClass('active');
    } else if ( activeBallIndex ) {
      var previousBall = milestoneBalls.eq( activeBallIndex - 1 );
      var previousBallPositionTop = previousBall.offset().top + (previousBall.parent().height() / 3);
      
      if (previousBallPositionTop > window.scrollY) {
        activeBall.removeClass('active');
        previousBall.addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(activeMilestone);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.info_wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.dot {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border: solid 4px green;
}

.active {
  border: solid 4px yellow;
  background-color: red;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: maroon;
  border: solid 4px green;
}

.text {}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_wrapper">
      <div class="text"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **on wheel** from jQuery.

```
$(window).on('wheel',function(e) {
  var mov = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
  if(mov > 0) {
    alert("up");
  }else {
    alert("down");
  }
});
```

This will sort out your problem regarding detection of scrolling direction.

Comment: Direction is reversed though. Up is negative.